# Saving the default processor architecture for tests in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, testing, architecture, settings, processor

I am using Visual Studio Community 15.7.5 and I have checked in my complete solution to github. It contains 3 projects, where one of them is using the google test framework. Additionally I am using the VS-extension "Google Test Adapter" from Christian Soltenborn.

Now I want to be able to clone my solution from github to an arbitrarily place
in my filesystem and be instant ready to compile and running all stuff inclusive the google tests WITHOUT modifying something at the solution-/project-settings.

In the sum it works now all fine, but for each clone I still have to set the **default processor architecture manually to x64**. This setting is NOT saved in the solution-/project-settings. I think this specific setting is saved in 
some file(s) in the folder .vs. But this folder is part of my .gitignore-file, because this directory should not be committed.

I also tried to create some XML-file in the solution with the suffix .runsettings, which I used then as "test setting file". This works, but
the path saved here seems to be an absolute path fixed to the actual directory of the solution. So I would need to assign manually the .runsettings-file for each new clone, which has another directory-location.

I could not find any real solution for this problem, and other people seems to have similar problems:
[How can I default VS Test Processor Architecture to x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513219/how-can-i-default-vs-test-processor-architecture-to-x64)

Who has got any idea, how to solve this problem? Also any dirty hacks are welcome, which do finally the job. I cannot imagine, that this 
problem (not really very exotic) is still present, although microsoft knows this "bug" for a long time!

Comment: That setting is saved in the .SUO file (solution user options). It's not a good idea to add this to version control. And the file name will be saved with full name, not relative name, so it will likely not work for your coworkers.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to be a feature/bug.
To permanently test in x64 you need to create a XXX.runsettings as a solution item, that sets x64 architecture, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2017):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: He already knows about this. But this doesn't save the TargetPlatform in the solution or project file. Every new clone of the repo will need to select the .runsettings file manually, just like selecting x64 as the default processor. OP is trying to fix that to the solution so nobody has to manually do that extra step.