# Can I update Test Default Runsettings to x64 for a Visual Studio 2019 solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, runsettings

Whenever I open up a VS 2017 project for the first time, or after an operation like git clean, I have to select "Test" -> "Test Settings" -> "Default Processor Architecture" and set it to x64. In VS 2019 (or 2017 if I missed some way to do this), how can I set the project to default to x64 so that it's embedded in the actual file so I don't have to repeat this action?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61971/test-explorer-default-architecture-not-remembered.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524801/saving-the-default-processor-architecture-for-tests-in-vs-2017

Comment: @HansPassant I always have the test explorer pinned, and I always open Visual Studio before opening the project so the 2018 solution in the first link doesn't work for me. The second link refers to setting it in a runsettings file, but I want it to be the default for Visual Studio, not on a per-runsettings basis, so the second link also doesn't work for me. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?